# new.js.haml is not rendered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am having a `form` which was designed as follows

```
= form_for :url => @question do |f|
  %table
    %thead
      %td
        = f.label :ques
      %tr
        = select_tag
```

options
    %tbody#questions

In my controller I have

```
def new
  @question = Question.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

In new.html.haml

```
:javascript
  $('select').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: window.location.href
    });
  });
```

Where I am wrong in the above coding? Why this page is not rendered in js format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `dataType : 'script'` to your ajax call parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I got the format, but my new.js.haml file is not loading.